# Internal server error for connect to baidu.com:443?

Tags: playframework-2.3

I'm running a Play!Framework 2.3 application that can be accessed publicly, and today, I noticed I had this exception that occured only three times on my log file :

! Internal server error, for (CONNECT) [www.baidu.com:443] ->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1234) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:228) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1088) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq(Regex.scala:206) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at play.docs.DocumentationHandler.maybeHandleDocRequest(DocumentationHandler.scala:65) ~[na:na]
    at play.docs.DocumentationHandler.maybeHandleDocRequest(DocumentationHandler.scala:33) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication.handleWebCommand(ApplicationProvider.scala:189) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:69) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:69) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:69) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:37) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:157) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:157) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:99) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:142) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) [netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

What is bothering me, is that the stacktrace doesn't contains any relation to my code.

- I tried to search on my whole project the mention of "baidu.com", nothing (well, exception that log file containing this stacktrace)
- I searched through the entire database of my project. No reference of baidu.com also.

Where does this come from? What is this? I don't like that too much :/

Thank you for your help.

Note: Someone also noted something strange, that same behavior, but connecting to alipay.com : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/-bHKgxY7jrI

I'm starting to wonder if there is no malicious file inside the Play!Framework archive!

I implemented a logger to see what was the request, and here's what I got :

```
URL : https://www.baidu.com/
      /
      www.baidu.com
IP :  222.186.21.70
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Headers :
  * Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  * Accept-Language : zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
  * Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
  * User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
  * Host : www.baidu.com
  * Proxy-Connection : Keep-Alive
```

The URL part should be a link to my app. When I do the test, the URL looks something like `/items/5`, not a full website!

It would looks like that connection tries to access baidu VIA my app. I don't know what/how/why!

Comment: I don't think there is any malicious file inside the framework. But the problem looks like coming from documentation (Line 65) : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-docs/src/main/scala/play/docs/DocumentationHandler.scala
I think someone tried to trick something on your website by trying to access the documentation... Is it accessible on your website ? http://yousite.com/@documentation ?

Comment: Indeed the @documentation is accessible, but what is the link with baidu.com/alipay.com ?

Comment: Good question. I tried to find where it is possible to pass some URL in parameter of the documentation but couldn't find out. Do you have a way of checking the URIs visited on your website ? Maybe Google Analytics can do it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, since it goes to the @documentation url, I don't have access here. I'll mount a honeypot on it to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I added an output of a request made by that thing. It appears that the IP is a proxy system (I connected to the http port of the ip, and translated the page).